# converting phone number into phone 'word' - python

Tags: python, if-statement, numbers, return

I want to convert given phone number into respective letters

```
0 -> 'a'
1 -> 'b'
2 -> 'c' etc.
```

E.g. the number 210344222 should get converted to the string 'cbadeeccc'.
I understand my return is wrong at the end which is where I am stuck, so can you please explain how I would instead return the letter conversions.

```
def phone(x):
    """
    >>> phone(22)
    'cc'
    >>> phone(1403)
    'bead'
    """
    result = "" 
    x = str(x)
    for ch in x: 
        if x == 0:
            print('a')
        elif x == 1:
            print('b')
        elif x == 3:
            print('c')
    return result
```

Comment: Yes I understand I dont go up to '4' so on but thats not what Im having trouble with so tried to simplify it for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try utilizing the built-in [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) method:

```
def phone(x):
    return ''.join((chr(int(i) + 97)) for i in x)

print(phone('210344222'))
```

Output:

```
cbadeeccc
```

Where `chr(97)` returns `'a'`, `chr(98)` returns `'b'`, and so on, hence the `int(i) + 97` bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a constant named [`ascii_lowercase` in the `string` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) that can be used to convert numbers into letters in the way you describe, you can use the number and get that index in `ascii_lowercase` to get the letter

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
phone_number = "210344222"
converted = ''.join(ascii_lowercase[int(i)] for i in phone_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use chr() and ord() and culcuate the 'a' + number

```
def phone(x):
    """
    >>> phone(22)
    'cc'
    >>> phone(1403)
    'bead'
    """
    result = "" 
    x = str(x)
    result = result.join([chr(int(ch) + ord('a')) for ch in x])
    return result

print(phone('22'))
print(phone('1403'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def phone(x):

    result = []

    x = str(x)
    for ch in x:
        if ch == '0':

            result.append('a')
        elif ch == '1':

            result.append('b')
        elif ch == '3':

            result.append('c')
    return ''.join(result)
```

Comment: I havent learnt append yet-is it only used for lists?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge . yes